# Firebase Auth error 17010 (account access disabled from too many failed login attempts) not being enforced?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17010 "Access to this account has
> been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts. You can
> immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again
> later." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access to this account has
> been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts. You can
> immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again
> later., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS}

I received this Firebase Auth iOS SDK error, as expected, after repeatedly trying to sign into an account with invalid credentials (for testing) but was unexpectedly able to sign into that account immediately thereafter using valid credentials. Why wasn't the warning in this error enforced? Or was the penalty just a few seconds? There is no documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this issue found here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/54 it seems that Firebase is a little vulnerable to brute force attacks only blocking successive attempts for a few seconds at a time. Firebase also does not have this currently publicly documented.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error, but as I have observed firebase allow up to 6 attempts before giving you the error "too many requests" that would disable the account temporarily which I am pretty sure cannot last over a minute (or a minute and a half) before being able to sign in again. I think further invalid login attempts after the previous 6 attempts adds few seconds to the penalty. Best thing to do is after 6 attempts wait for about 1 1/2 minute and try to sign in again.