# Getting firebase_auth/invalid-credential on Flutter - Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkFvQ0SaT1I

I used the `flutterfire configure` to automatically generate a `firebase_options.dart` to my project. I enable signed in with email and password in my Firebase project settings. I manually created a user in the Firebase console and logged in successfully one time. When I modified the UI a bit, I tried again and I started getting this error:

> E/flutter (17561): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied
> auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.

I tried logging out with `Firebase.instance.signOut()`.
I tried reconfiguring the project.

After several tries, I received the following message in the debug console:

> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(17561): Initial task failed for action
> RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - We have
> blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try
> again later. [ Access to this account has been temporarily disabled
> due to many failed login attempts. You can immediately restore it by
> resetting your password or you can try again later. ]

It seems there is nothing wrong with auth configuration or credentials, as the Firebase was noticing my login attemps. I tried reseting the password to a super easy one. It did not work.

Why it was working one time and in the same day, a few minutes later, it stopped working?
Anyone has ideias?

*EDIT: I just tested `FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and it worked fine too. Login stills giving me the problems described above.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of the issue discussed at [Firebase Auth Error 17010: Account access disabled from too many failed login attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214057/firebase-auth-error-17010-account-access-disabled-from-too-many-failed-login-at). Firebase Authentication can block further attempts if the number of failed login attempts exceeds a certain threshold. However, the documentation listing errors and their codes ([Firebase Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)) does not provide detailed information about how this mechanism functions, possibly for security reasons.

Based on experiences shared by others, you may be able to try logging in again after waiting a few minutes. (Note that repeated invalid attempts could result in longer waiting periods.)

Comment: The problem is not about getting access disabled from too many login attempts, is about getting invalid-credential when trying to login.